# Referring to uncle's wife as "aunt" vs. nephew's wife as "niece"

Tags: kinship-terms, pragmatics

I may be going out on a pragmatic/cultural limb here, but is there an asymmetry in the commonly accepted practice of referring to your uncle's wife as "aunt" but not referring to your nephew's wife as "niece".

If so, why is there an asymmetry? Deference to the older generation within a family? Is the spouse of a nephew/niece seem as less part of the family?

Comment: Niece has an interesting etymology since it was used at one point or another to refer to: "A female relative, esp. a cousin", "A granddaughter, or more remote female descendant", "A male relative, esp. a nephew" (OED). Only the last one seems to be still in use today, although it's restricted to African-American use.

Comment: I would think this is obvious: the "aunt" was there ever since you were born. The nephew's wife is a new addition that takes some time getting used to.

Comment: It’s an interesting observation. Aunts and uncles are either blood relatives (parent’s siblings) or the spouses of those selfsame blood relatives; but nephews and nieces are only blood relatives. It’s like that at least in most Western European languages as far as I can think, so it’s not just a case of English being asymmetrical. I’m not sure there’s any way to conclusively answer _why_ this is so, though. History ended up with the words being used like that.

Comment: I suggest that’s purely about culture and community, not English in particular nor even language in general 

I know so many people who always refer to nephews’ wives as “nieces”, anything else would seem rather perverse, at least outside official documents.

Isn't this more about family customs?

Comment: FWIW, when I was growing up many of my parents' friends were addressed as Aunt so-and-so, or Uncle so-and-so, even though I knew they weren't my real uncles or aunts. For a man married to an aunt it's not much of a stretch to go from "He's Uncle Fred" to "He's my uncle".

Comment: Spouses of aunts/uncles are more likely to take on a caring role when you're a child; in such a situation, it's usual to address with an affectionate term such as aunt/uncle. (There's also the issue of respect and not referring to an adult by their first name, which is maybe dying out a bit but still found.) While your parents may see their siblings often, it's less common to encounter adult nieces or nephews because you'll be long out of your family home, and they'll be gone from theirs; and they probably won't babysit you, so you'll be less close.

Comment: I've no idea if what the OP says is even true, and it would be nice to have some *evidence* before creating theories. I don't have any married nieces or nephews, but if I was very close to them and their spouse, it's not impossible I'd come up with some term of endearment.